# Verify screen name existence

Tags: python, django, error-handling, tweepy

I have a django app which uses tweepy to get the last tweet of a specific person, given his/her screen_name. However, as the screen_name field is optional for my application, it is possible that sometimes I have screen_names that are empty or just do not exist.

However, if this occurs (if I use the user_lookup, for example), the Tweepy launches a `TweepyError` exception, and then my application stops. Is there a way to handle this?  I just would like to verify the existence of a Twitter's screen_name and return a `True` or a `False` statement, without stopping my application.

Comment: It depends on your application purpose, if you think a user can use your application without any login(if you use twitter as authentication) or account in twitter(as social account, will definitely occurs often). First solution create a basic account with basics info/no editable(locked field but multi logged)... If answer does not help you give us more: purpose code example...

Comment: How about a `try...except` statement? Did you try that?

Answer (score 3):

This will help you out. This will help you get the validity/existence status of each twitter handle present in the **users** array.

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler



consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = "" 


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
users=["twitterhandle1","twitterhandle2"]

for x in users:
    try:
        u=api.get_user(x)
        print (u.id_str)
        print (u.screen_name)
    except Exception:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to prevent your application from stopping when Tweepy raises a `TweepyError` exception, then this is a classic case of using `python`'s `try...except` statements.

```
try:
    # do whatever with tweepy here
except TweepyError:
    # do what you want to when the lookup fails
    pass
```

However... you mentioned that the twitter name is optional for your application, which is causing the problem. I don't see why you can't put in a simple check for this. Let's say your field name is `twitter_name` and `model_instance` is an instance of the model to which it belongs:

```
if model_instance.twitter_name is not None:
    # do the tweepy stuff here
```